# How do I watermark an existing .epub file?

Tags: c#, epub, watermark

May I know which strategy I've to follow in order to watermark an existing epub file? Any suggestion for existing code or libraries?

In particular i'd like to insert the watermark in ONE page of the document.

Comment: Any encryption or DRM?  A watermark in a normal epub is easier removed than added.

Comment: Strictly DRM... is it impossible???

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion on the subject,

http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=75585

There seems to be a few avenues of exploration. Which one suits your needs best is really down to what you require the watermark for.